# R: Issues with removing one row from a dataframe into a new dataframe

Tags: r, select, filter

I have a table with details of sample sites (site id, latitude and longitude, depth, diameter etc). It's confidential, but essentially looks like this:

```
id   location     description       EASTING      NORTHING    depth     diameter
Q111 Deal Rd      Trent             2593302      6201956     3          NA
X123 Wall St      NA                1602121      5602121     5          0.2
A456 Hill Rd      McDonald's Farm   1604567      5604121     NA         NA
D999 Mount Ave    Baylis            1528677      5413458     4          0.3
```

Two of the rows have incorrect co-ordinates, so I'm trying to make two dfs, one with just one incorrect data row and the other with all the rest of the data, then fix the coordinates and bind the tables together again.

The first time I tried this I used:

```
sites$res_num<-as.numeric(sites$EASTING)
temp1<-sites[which(sites$EASTING==2593302),]
temp2<-sites %>% filter(EASTING != "2593302" | is.na(EASTING))
temp1$EASTING<-1683222
temp1$NORTHING<-5671239
temp1$res_num<-1683222
sites<-rbind(temp1, temp2)
```

Worked fine. (I admit I don't know why I got told to add the extra column first). Now I'm trying to do the other row, but whenever I try the "temp1<-sites[which(sites$EASTING==2593302),]" code I get a df with 0 obs. of 18 variables.

I've also tried

```
temp1<-sites %>% filter(EASTING == "1528677")
```

but get the same empty df. I can literally pull out any other row by changing the easting cordinate here, but not that one. I'm copying and pasting the number from the df, so I don't understand what is special about that one row.

Edit: EASTING is definitely numeric:

```
    > str(sites)
'data.frame':   207 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ id              : chr  "tn20 ko A" "G01560" "Chester St" "CTK20" ...
 $ type            : chr  "bore" "bore" "bore" "bore" ...
 $ NGMP            : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ LawaID          : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ location        : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ description     : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ EASTING         : num  1692308 1683222 NA NA NA ...
```

Comment: `easting` might be a character. Could you edit your question to include the output of `str(sites)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not seeing the data types and actual values of your data makes it a bit harder to answer. But I have a suspicion:

What is the response to `typeof(sites$EASTING)`? If it is character, my suspicion would be that you have trailing or leading whitespace. Have a look of the response to `tibble(test_data = c("1", "    1")) |> filter(test_data == 1)`. That's probably also why a colleague advised you to turn the row into numeric (see the result of `tibble(test_data = c("1", "    1")) |> mutate(test_data = as.numeric(test_data)) |> filter(test_data == 1)`). If that is the case, you would get away with `temp1<-sites %>% filter(res_num == "1528677")`, but I strongly suggest using str_trim on the column instead to get rid of the extra white space or using numeric values instead.

BTW, your current solution also changes the order of the rows in your dataframe. If you turn EASTING into a numeric column, you can also update individual values like so:

`sites[which(sites$EASTING==2593302),"EASTING"] <- 1683222`

And then use the new value for EASTING to update the NORTHING variable:

`sites[which(sites$EASTING==1683222),"NORTHING"] <- 5671239`

The direct approach doesn't change the order in the data frame (both approaches, however, imply that all rows that have 2593302 as their EASTING value, should be updated to 1683222 and have a NORTHING value of 5671239. Please be aware that you can really mess up your data if you are not careful using bulk approaches like this. I hope that helps.

Comment: If you use the tidyverse you can also use `mutate` in connection with `if_else` to update the values in place. `if_else` has the advantage that it will make sure that the data type is the same throughout the column. Base R's datatype casting is very dynamic and new R programmers often unknowingly change the data type of their columns using approaches like outlined above.

Comment: Thanks!  `typeof(sites$EASTING)` gave me `"double"` (and `str(sites)` gave me `"num"` for that column), so I don't know if you can have leading/trailing whitespace with numbers? 
But updating the individual value in the original dataframe worked - and in this case the coordinates are unique so I'm confident I haven't changed more than one record. That was the original reason for wanting to pull out one row at a time and change it.